# Is there a better way to repeat code other than using def

Tags: python-3.x, space-efficiency

I have

```
    print(randint(0,12))
```

Is there a quicker easier way of being able to execute this three times in a line other than copying it all out or using

```
    def RandNum(number):
        print(randint(0,12))
```

so is there just a way I can run the first piece of code really quickly instead of then going on and using.

```
    (RandNum("number"))
```

When ever I need the random number?

Thanks. I want to find as many alternative methods to doing this as possible.

Comment: Why you don't use a loop? since you want to use it 3 times.

Comment: It's not just purely three times in one certain place, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps!!

```
from random import randint

def RandNum(number):
    l = []
    for _ in range(number):
        l.append(randint(0,12))
    print " ".join(map(str, l))

RandNum(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want the random randint to execute only 3 times. This is how

```
from random import randint
timesexecuted = int(0)
while timesexecuted < 3:
    print(randint(0,12))
    timesexecuted = timesexecuted + 1

#after this anything you want happen next.
```

This method is most efficient when you are looping things larger amounts of times, such as, you want to executed `print(randint(0,12))` over hundreds of times, this method is probably easiest to write.

Explanation

`timesexecuted` is set to `int(0)` since no loops have been run and we need to define `timesexecuted`. We need to run a loop 3 times so to do that, in the loop, we add on 1 to `timesexecuted` with `timesexecuted + 1` and so once `timesexecuted` is up to 3 (starts on 0, does 1 loop, is now 1, after another loop, becomes 2, does a third loop, is now 3). And since we have the loop under `while timesexecuted < 3:`, as `timesexecuted` is now 3 because the loop has run 3 times, `timesexecuted < 3` is no longer true and the loop will run no more. The `3` can also be changed to any number, making this method probably the best if looping many times. (eg. Looping this program 200 times with `while timesexecuted < 200:`)

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks very much, also extra thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3, you can use the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) function with a list of three numbers. The optional parameter `sep` has default value of a space, so you don't have to define it if you need three numbers separated by a space.

```
print(*[random.randint(0, 12) for _ in range(3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is there a reason why you cannot copy out 'randint'? This is the most efficient solution, however does involve some typing:

```
number1 = random.randint(0,12)
```

If you don't mind using a function (which I recommend) try setting a variable using the function:

```
def RandNum():
        return random.randint(0,12)

number1 = RandNum()
number2 = RandNum()
```

This will make the numbers random, but constant throughout the program.
Good luck on your program!

P.S. The return command stops the function and 'returns' to the main program. e.g. if I have the code:

```
def function():
        return 3
        return 2
        return 1
```

Only 3 will be returned and used by the main program.

Comment: Reason being so is I want to achieve maximum efficiency there are many people better at Python than me on this so why not ask, I personally don't know all of them.

Comment: @Merlindima The most efficient way of doing this is to declare all the variables on the same line, therefore using the first solution and combining the three gives `number1, number2, number3 = random.randint(0,12), random.randint(0,12), random.randint(0,12)`